# How much fuel is necessary to cause delta-v?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, rocket-equation

For a project, I need to calculate how much thrust and how much fuel I need for getting into LEO.

What I know:

- Delta-V necessary ($\approx 9.4$ km/s)
- Dry (empty spacecraft mass)

What I don't know:

- How much fuel I'm bringing
- How much thrust I need

Are there any good ways of calculating this?

Comment: What's the extra 1.3km/s for?

Comment: "Atmospheric and gravity drag associated with launch typically adds 1.3–1.8 km/s to the launch vehicle delta-v" -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit#Orbital_characteristics)

Comment: That's included in the normally quoted 9400m/s. Orbital velocity is ~7800m/s.

Comment: Hint: your thrust needs to be greater than the vehicle weight at liftoff.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) tells you how much delta-V you get for a given exhaust velocity and full/empty mass ratio per stage. Typically you'll want to divide the total 9400m/s requirement into two (or more) stages and work backward from the uppermost stage. Select an appropriate engine for the stage, decide how much dry tankage/structural mass you need per mass of fuel, solve.

As Organic Marble notes, the first-stage thrust needs to exceed the weight of the fully loaded rocket, or it won't lift off. Typically the thrust to weight ratio starts at somewhere between 1.15:1 and 1.5:1. (Upper stages can relax that limit a little bit but will usually start close to 1:1 to maximize the amount of fuel they bring.) Pick an engine and add multiples of them until your thrust is sufficient!

The devil is in the details, of course. I suggest running the numbers from an existing rocket to make sure you understand the principles before trying your own.

Here's part of a spreadsheet that I use for quick-and-dirty feasibility tests. Making it useful to you is left as an exercise.

- Stage mass: total mass of an individual stage, fully loaded with propellant.
- Prop fraction: fraction of stage mass which is propellant.
- Structure: structural (non-propellant) mass of stage.
- Propellant: propellant mass of fully loaded stage.
- Upper: total mass of all stages above this one, fully loaded.
- Ballast: inert payload mass attached to the stage.
- M0: total mass of the rocket at ignition of the stage.
- M1: total mass of the rocket at burnout of the stage.
- ISP: specific impulse of the stage's engines.
- Thrust: total thrust of the stage's engines.
- Delta-v: single stage delta-V contribution, summing to total delta V below.
- G0: acceleration at stage ignition, in g (equivalent to TWR).
- G1: acceleration at stage burnout.

Masses in metric tons, ISP in seconds, thrust in kN, delta-V in m/s. I use the sea level specific impulse of the first stage engine, which yields a slight underestimate for delta-v because ISP will increase over the course of the burn.

Value view:
[image]

Formula view:
[image]

Comment: Ooooo the spreadsheets are a very nice touch

Comment: Dang this is a good answer. I’ll wait 24hr and accept unless there are other better answers

Comment: oh my god, I didn't know that Formula View could be done.  That's real  good.

Comment: @ErinAnne I didn't either until today!

Comment: @ErinAnne `CTRL+\`` will turn it on and off.